# Change bonding thresholds in NBO Calculations?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-chemistry, orbitals

I'm looking at a system with really long bond lengths, and I'm trying to determine if there's any interaction at all between orbitals on two particular atoms.

I'm using NBO7 with the GENNBO interface, and I'm trying to figure out how to change the threshold for either what the program recognizes as a bond (optimally using atomic distances) OR for the 3c-4e bond searching.

Essentially, currently the 3CHB input keyword's 3C-4E output looks like this:

```
     3-Center, 4-Electron A:-B-:C Hyperbonds (A-B :C <=> A: B-C)
              [threshold for detection: 33.3%]

                                                  NBOs       3-center hybrids
                                              -------------  ----------------
       Hyperbond A:-B-:C   %A-B/%B-C   occ    BD(A-B) LP(C)  h(A)  h(B)  h(C)
      -------------------  ---------  ------  ------- -----  ----  ----  ----
   1.  C  2:- C  3-: C  4  61.4/38.6  3.0548      37     18    41    42    18
```

I'd like to change the threshold for detection to be lower. I'm not finding anything in the manual that would indicate how to do this; if anyone has any examples of how to change this threshold I'd be very grateful. Thank you!